# Should I consider '\f', '\v' as newline characters in .c file?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a C program lexical analyzer using flex.

I read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases and was told that vertical tab `\v` and form feed `\f` is kept before the line-combining and the decomposing phases.

Should I consider them as newlines characters just like `\n`?

looking forward to any reply, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard says in chapter 5.1.1.2 "Translation phases" for phase 3:

> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white-space characters (including comments). *[...]* Whether each nonempty sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is implementation-defined.

Since `\v` and `\f` are white-space characters, it is up to you to replace them with a single space or not. But you should not replace them with new-lines.

Comment: Thanks. And I wonder what ```\v``` and ```\f``` are used for in a .c source file.

Comment: To be honest, I never found them. However, some coding style guides might use them to structure printouts. Some of these guides are ... hrm ... y'know ... weird. -- BTW, the preferred way to say "Thank you" is to mark the answer, to avoid such a comment. ;-)